# How to validate an email from JTextField

Tags: java, swing, validation, jtextfield, joptionpane

Just like the title says, I want to display a jOptionPane if there's a missing specific character in a jTextField. Let's say that character is "@".

I tried something like this:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   
   String email = (String)txtEmail.getText();
   if (!email.equals(email) && email.equals("@")){
      jOptionPane1.showMessageDialog(null, "Please"); 
   }
}
```

However, I can't get this to work.
I also tried using `contains()` and `contentEquals()` but I don't know how to use it properly so I had changed the code. 
Searching on Google also doesn't help because I can't find what I want.
Please consider helping. BTW, I'm using netbeans.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're trying to validate an email, use [`String.matches(regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29)

Here is an imlementation of the email regex validation patter from [**this site**](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-email-address-with-regular-expression/). An explanation of the regex can also be found on the site.

```
private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = 
    "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
    + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

if (!email.matches(EMAIL_PATTERN)) {}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   
    String email = txtEmail.getText();
    if (!email.contains("@")) {
        jOptionPane1.showMessageDialog(null, "Please"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
:D
I'll remember this.

Comment: Out of interest how where you using contains?

Comment: How do I use contains that it leads me to changing it?
Like this `if (!email.contains(email + "@"))`